# Como deixar botões fixados em div flutuante

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho no meu sistema uma situação semelhante a essa que dei de exemplo. Um bootstrap modal que pode abrir em basicamente qualquer local da tela. Este modal não ocupa toda tela. Dentro desse modal, são listados alguns registros, conforme o contexto. Nesse modal, tenho uma div com os botões de manutenção dos registros (editar, excluir, incluir, etc..). Gostaria que essa div com os botões ficasse sempre no canto inferior direito do modal, fixado (pois o modal é scrollável, conforme a quantidade de registros), mas não estou conseguindo fazer. Já tentei colocar `position: fixed` e uma `margin-left` calculada na hora, mas não funcionou como eu queria

```css
.botoes-modal{
width: 120px; 
height: 40px; 
background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 200px;">
<table>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
</table>
<div id="botoes-acao" class="botoes-modal">
  Clique para editar
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nota que se você quer posicionar um elemento em relação ao seu `parent` ou antecessor deve utilizar `position:absolute`, com o `position:fixed` o elemento é posicionado em relação à janela do navegador, desta forma, para posicionar a `div` dos botões de ações, sabendo que a `div` pode aparecer em qualquer lugar da tela, devemos sempre pensar na sua posição com relação ao seu `parent` então no evento que é chamado quando o modal é exibido podemos posicionar a `div` dos botões com base na posição `top` e `left` do modal. O valor fixo "160" serve somente para este exemplo, você deve identificar qual o valor utilizar no seu modal, somar a altura do modal não funciona neste caso.

Nota que deixei o código do evento comentado, o código está bem autoexplicativo, espero que ajude. Segue um snippet de exemplo:

```js
/*$("#modal").on('show', function(event){
     posicionaBotoes();
});*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  posicionaBotoes();
});

function posicionaBotoes() {
  var modal = $("#modal");
  $(".botoes-modal").css('right', modal.offset().left);
  $(".botoes-modal").css('top', modal.offset().top + 160);
}
```

```css
.botoes-modal {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="modal" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 200px; border:1px solid red;">
<table>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
<tr><td>teste</td><td>teste</td></tr>
</table>
<div id="botoes-acao" class="botoes-modal">
  Clique para editar
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fica aí uma ideia. Usando position `fixed` dentro de uma `absolute`.

```css
#modal {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#absolute {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 120px;
}

#botoes-acao {
  position: fixed; /* não defina top/bottom/left/right */
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 200px; border:1px solid red;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="absolute">
    <div id="botoes-acao" class="botoes-modal">
      Clique para editar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Defina a div "PAI" que está com 200px de altura com position: relative;

Na div com os botões, defina o position fixed mas deixe zerado o bottom. Assim o botão ficará sempre fixo no rodapé da DIV. Para alinhar totalmente a direita, use right: 0.

Lembre-se sempre de utilizar as propriedades top, left, bottom right ao utilizar a propriedade position.

O código ficará assim:

```
<div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 200px; position: relative;">

.botoes-modal {
width: 120px;
height: 40px;
background-color: green;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0; }
```

Comment: Desse jeito não funciona. Eu já havia tentado, e ele fica no canto da tela. Preciso que ele fique no canto da modal